# How can I make Gmail in Edge my default email app in Windows 11

Tags: email, windows-11, gmail, microsoft-edge

I have this working perfectly with Chrome and Windows 10. But there doesn't seem to be any setting in Edge. All instructions online I've tried such as https://cynmackley.com/2023/01/10/make-gmail-the-default-email-in-win-10/ don't mention how to do this for Edge.

It seems firstly you need to make the default app in Windows settings your web browser which I have done.

However that just opens a blank tab in Edge. How do I make it go to Gmail and compose an email when I click a mailto hyperlink?

Comment: I'd say click the 'Install App' option (it might be called something different in Edge, that's what it is in Chrome, but I know there is/was an option in Edge, then set that through Settings. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the setting in Edge is buried under **Cookies and site permissions**.

Here you should be able to see protocol handlers. It's not enough to just have them there, you need to click **...** and add them as a default:

[image]